# d3.js update y axis domain when dragging

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a chart using zoom behavior on the x axis. I define it like this:

```
zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
           .x(x)
           .on("zoom", zoomed)
```

I am displaying a candle chart using this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/abeppu/1074045

This is how i define yScale:

```
y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }))
        .range([height, 0]);
```

What I want is to be able to update the domain of the y scale when dragging and zooming the data. This is a draft:

```
function zoomed() {
   dv = getVisibleData();
   y.domain(d3.extent(dv, function (d) { return d.close; }));
   // rest of the zoom function
}
```

How can I achieve this kind of behavior?

Comment: Could you simply add the y scale to the zoom behaviour like you're doing for the x scale?

Comment: The case is I don't want the user to be able to zoom the data vertically.

Comment: I want the y scale to be updated accordingly to the displayed data